# Invalid operands to binary

Tags: objective-c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

I have a method to check weather a number is even or odd:

```
   -(BOOL)numberIsEven:(unsigned int *)x {


  if (x & 1)
 {
  return TRUE;
 }
 else
{
 return FALSE;
  }
}
```

however whenever I compile it I get the error:

```
Invalid operands to binary %
```

So it's compiling into assembly as a modulus function and failing, somehow, however if I use a modulus based function (arguably slower) I get the same error!

Help me stack overflow

Thanks - 
Ollie

Comment: `if (isTrue) { return true; } else { return false; }` paradigm. Oh boy.

Comment: Aside from all the other issues, when you fix the bug of not dereferencing the pointer, your method name is really rubbish since it will return true if *x is odd.

Comment: Could you post the real code and error message?  What you've posted is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is a pointer.  The modulo operator will not work on pointers.

```
return (*x & 1);
```

This dereferences the pointer, then returns the result of the modulo (implictly cast to a BOOL)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're reading the error message wrong and it really says "Invalid operands to binary &".

The reason it says that is "x" is a pointer, so you need to say:

```
if (*x & 1)
```

not

```
if (x & 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because (aside from the fact that your code contains numerous typos) x is defined as a pointer. A pointer cannot have modulus performed on it, the result of that is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
return *x & 1;
```

Since `x` is a pointer to an int, you need to deference it first.

Alternately, you can change the signature to take an `unsigned int`.  I don't see any advantage to passing a pointer in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isOdd(unsigned int x) {
    return (bool)(x&1);
}

bool isOdd_by_ptr(unsigned int * p) {
    return isOdd( *p );
}
```

Except that this is actually C, so you don't get anything by casting to bool.

```
#define IS_ODD( X ) (1 & (X) )

#define IS_ODD_BY_PTR( P ) (1 & *(P) )
```

Work just fine.

Comment: Here's something interesting to try: `bool isOdd(int x) { return !isEven(x); }`, `bool isEven(int x) { return !isodd(x); }` =D